# Strongly continuous semigroup of operators which cannot be extended to a group

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Let $X$ be a Banach space. We call a family of bounded operators $(T(t))_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ a strongly continuous group if it satisfies the properties of the [strongly continuous semigroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup#Formal_definition) but for $t\in \mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{R^+}$. So we can see that every strongly continuous group is a strongly continuous semigroup.

I am just asking if there's a strongly continuous semigroup which cannot be extended to a strongly continuous group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest case I know is the translation $T(t)$ semigroup on $L^{2}[0,\infty)$ defined by $(T(t)f)(x)=f(x+t)$. There's no way to invert once you've lost part of the function.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the Heat semigroup on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$: for $t>0$,
$$U(t)g=K(t)\ast g$$
where
$$K(t)=(4\pi t)^{-n/2}e^{-|x|/4t}$$
is the heat kernel. $U(t)$ is a strongly continuous semigroupo (of contractions). Let's show that it cannot be extended to a group ($U(t)$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$) on $L^2$. If such a group eventually exists, it should satisfy $$U(t)\circ U(-t)=U(0)=Id$$  for all $t>0$: then, for all $g\in L^2$,
$$K(t)\ast U(-t)g=g$$
Applying Fourier transorm we have
$e^{-|\xi|^2t}\widehat{U(-t)g}=\hat{g}$, then
$$\widehat{U(-t)g}=e^{|\xi|^2t}\hat{g},$$
absurd, since $e^{|\xi|^2t}\hat{g}$ is not, in general, an element of $L^2$.

Comment: I choose T.A.E 's answer maybe because it is simple, But I also like your example since it concerns maybe the Laplace transform. I would accept both answers if it is possible.

Comment: No problem man, i'm happy my answer was useful to you